# How to know if there were any modifications after running rsync?

Tags: rsync

I want to use rsync on a linux host and rsync one-way to windows machine (using cwrsync). After I run a sync, is there way to know if there actually were any updates or not? (something like a 'total checksum' for the whole repository I'm syncing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the `--stats` option give you what you want?